# react-hot-loader: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string error updating the screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hot-loader

I'm trying to build an isomorphic ReactJS app boilerplate using [rect-redux-universal-hot-example](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example) .

I'm using [react-hot-loader](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader) for hot module reloading (hmr).

My page in browser is not being reloaded automatically once I change some App component data. I'm getting the following error in the browser:

```
[HMR] connected
main-32cd5038bd66f14eeceb.js:12141 [HMR] bundle rebuilding
main-32cd5038bd66f14eeceb.js:12149 [HMR] bundle rebuilt in 530ms
main-32cd5038bd66f14eeceb.js:30888 [HMR] Checking for updates on the server...
main-32cd5038bd66f14eeceb.js:1000 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.
printWarning @ main-32cd5038bd66f14eeceb.js:1000
main-32cd5038bd66f14eeceb.js:30976 [HMR] Cannot check for update (Full reload needed)
handleError @ main-32cd5038bd66f14eeceb.js:30976
main-32cd5038bd66f14eeceb.js:30977 [HMR] Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.
    at invariant (http://localhost:3001/dist/main-32cd5038bd66f14eeceb.js:946:15)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.instantiateReactComponent [as _instantiateReactComponent] (http://localhost:3001/dist/main-32cd5038bd66f14eeceb.js:11215:55)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._updateRenderedComponent (http://localhost:3001/dist/main-32cd5038bd66f14eeceb.js:19852:24)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._performComponentUpdate (http://localhost:3001/dist/main-32cd5038bd66f14eeceb.js:19815:10)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.updateComponent (http://localhost:3001/dist/main-32cd5038bd66f14eeceb.js:19736:12)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.receiveComponent (http://localhost:3001/dist/main-32cd5038bd66f14eeceb.js:19638:10)
    at Object.receiveComponent (http://localhost:3001/dist/main-32cd5038bd66f14eeceb.js:3479:22)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._updateRenderedComponent (http://localhost:3001/dist/main-32cd5038bd66f14eeceb.js:19845:23)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._performComponentUpdate (http://localhost:3001/dist/main-32cd5038bd66f14eeceb.js:19815:10)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.updateComponent (http://localhost:3001/dist/main-32cd5038bd66f14eeceb.js:19736:12)
handleError @ main-32cd5038bd66f14eeceb.js:30977
main-32cd5038bd66f14eeceb.js:946 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.
    at invariant (main-32cd5038bd66f14eeceb.js:946)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.instantiateReactComponent [as _instantiateReactComponent] (main-32cd5038bd66f14eeceb.js:11215)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._updateRenderedComponent (main-32cd5038bd66f14eeceb.js:19852)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._performComponentUpdate (main-32cd5038bd66f14eeceb.js:19815)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.updateComponent (main-32cd5038bd66f14eeceb.js:19736)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.receiveComponent (main-32cd5038bd66f14eeceb.js:19638)
    at Object.receiveComponent (main-32cd5038bd66f14eeceb.js:3479)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._updateRenderedComponent (main-32cd5038bd66f14eeceb.js:19845)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._performComponentUpdate (main-32cd5038bd66f14eeceb.js:19815)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.updateComponent (main-32cd5038bd66f14eeceb.js:19736)
```

Here is my setup:

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-0"],

  "plugins": [
    "transform-runtime",
    "add-module-exports",
    "transform-react-display-name",
    "flow-runtime",
    "react-hot-loader/babel"
  ]
}
```

**client.js**

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';
import App from './component/App/app';

const NextApp = require('./component/App/app').default;

const dest = document.getElementById('content');

const render = (Component) => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer>
      <Component />
    </AppContainer>,
    dest
  );
};

render(App);

console.log('MODULE HOT:');
console.log(module.hot);

if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('./component/App/app', () => {
        render(NextApp);
    });
}
```

**App**

```
import React from 'react';

const App = () => (

        <div className="wrapper">
            <h1>This is my App!!!!</h1>
        </div>

);

export default App;
```

**dev.config**

```
require('babel-polyfill');

// Webpack config for development
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var assetsPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../static/dist');
var host = (process.env.HOST || 'localhost');
var port = (+process.env.PORT + 1) || 3001;

// https://github.com/halt-hammerzeit/webpack-isomorphic-tools
var WebpackIsomorphicToolsPlugin = require('webpack-isomorphic-tools/plugin');
var webpackIsomorphicToolsPlugin = new WebpackIsomorphicToolsPlugin(require('./webpack-isomorphic-tools'));

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, '..'),
  entry: {
    'main': [
      'react-hot-loader/patch',
      'webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=http://' + host + ':' + port + '/__webpack_hmr',
      './src/client.js'
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: assetsPath,
    filename: '[name]-[hash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name]-[chunkhash].js',
    publicPath: 'http://' + host + ':' + port + '/dist/'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ['babel-loader', 'eslint-loader']},
      { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' },
      { test: /\.less$/, loader: 'style-loader!css?modules&importLoaders=2&sourceMap&localIdentName=[local]___[hash:base64:5]!autoprefixer?browsers=last 2 version!less?outputStyle=expanded&sourceMap' },
      { test: /\.scss$/, loader: 'style-loader!css?modules&importLoaders=2&sourceMap&localIdentName=[local]___[hash:base64:5]!autoprefixer?browsers=last 2 version!sass?outputStyle=expanded&sourceMap' },
      { test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
      { test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
      { test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream" },
      { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file-loader" },
      { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml" },
      { test: webpackIsomorphicToolsPlugin.regular_expression('images'), loader: 'url-loader?limit=10240' }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      'src',
      'node_modules'
    ],
    extensions: ['*', '.json', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  plugins: [
    // hot reload
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/webpack-stats\.json$/),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      __CLIENT__: true,
      __SERVER__: false,
      __DEVELOPMENT__: true,
      __DEVTOOLS__: true  // <-------- DISABLE redux-devtools HERE
    }),
    webpackIsomorphicToolsPlugin.development()
  ]
};
```

Where can I find the error?

Answer (score 0):

Right now in the console we're seeing an error crop up because AppContainer.dev is attempting to render the Redbox module export but the component sits on .default due to babelification and AppContainer is using require().enter code here

My temporary fix:

```
const mount = document.getElementById('app');

render(
  <AppContainer errorReporter={({ error }) => {throw error}}>
    <App store={store} />
  </AppContainer>,
  mount
);
```